# Sequelize addColumn migration always referring public schema

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have an Express application with **Sequelize** as ORM and **PostgreSQL** as database.
Database is setup in such a manner where every tenants in my application will have different schemas.The migration files which exists in my application contains addColumn/removeColumn migrations.
But when i am running npx sequelize-cli db:migrate command, i am getting the following error.

ERROR: relation "public.table_name" does not exist

The above error is throwing only for the migration files that contains either addColumn/removeColumn migrations.
Also  i am nowhere referring to public schema(even deleted the public schema from db).
Is there a way to run the migrations against a particular schema(say test_schema) in Sequelize without hardcoding the schema name in the migration files?

Update #2

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    try {
      await queryInterface.addColumn('table_name', 'new_field_name', {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      });
      return Promise.resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  },

  down: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    try {
      await queryInterface.removeColumn('table_name','new_field_name');
      return Promise.resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  }
};
```

---

Above is the code for addColumn migration .

Comment: Please show an example of a migration with addColumn/removeColumn

Comment: @Anatoly i have updated the question with the example migration.Please see.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an extended syntax of addColumn/removeColumn like this:

```
const { tableSchemas } = require('../config.json')
const tableName = 'table_name'
...
module.exports = {
  up: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    // adding transaction because we have several changes
    await queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
      for (const tableSchema of tableSchemas) {
        const table = { schema: tableSchema, tableName: tableName }
        await queryInterface.addColumn(table, 'new_field_name', {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        }, { transaction });
      }
    })
  },

  down: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    // adding transaction because we have several changes
    await queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
      for (const tableSchema of tableSchemas) {
        const table = { schema: tableSchema, tableName: tableName }
        await queryInterface.removeColumn(table,'new_field_name', { transaction });
      }
    })
  }
};
```

Comment: i am looking for a way  without hardcoding the schema name in the migration files

Comment: you can import a config file in a migration file and use a schema name from it.

Comment: i think it is not possible in my case since i need to run migrations against 5 schemas.Please share your thoughts

Comment: Where is a source of 5 schema names?

Comment: right now i am hardcoding schema in the config.json file

Comment: And wgere do you wish to store schema names instead of config.json?

Comment: in some env files.This is the confusion,how to run that migration against each schema even though we are specifying it in a config/env files

Comment: Do you use a DB storage for storing applied migrations?

Comment: No. Not using any

Comment: If you can import env files to your migration file then you just need a for loop to execute 'up' or 'down' content of a migration.

Comment: can u suggest how that can be done in the migration file i have included in my Question

Comment: Thank you for the answer.On doing the way you proposed; say i have four schemas, all the 4 migrations will be generated in the same folder right.so i won't be able to run migration against a particular schema if such a requirement came.is there any such options like that ?

Comment: you can try yo create different config sections and link them to a certain NODE environment variable (like NODE_ENV=development) and then set the variable before executing a migration.

Comment: not sure if this will still be useful, but preceding table name with schema `schema."table_name"` worked for me. Seuelize version 6.6.2 and postgressql 12.